# Reversing an array of the first n numbers in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, reverse

My function is going into an infinite loop. The problem is to reverse the first n integers of an array ex: array `{2,4,1,3}` would be reversed to `{4,2,1,3}` since the first number is a 2, it switches the first 2 numbers and etc.

Any ideas? :)

My code:

```
int *reverse(int *arr,int n)
{
    int w; 
    int q=arr[0]-1; 
    int first_value = arr[0];

    for(w=0; w<=first_value; w++) 
    {
        arr[w] = arr[q];
        q--;
    }

    return (arr); 
}
```

Comment: What is q for? Use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this supposed to do when `arr[0] > n`, where `n` is assumedly the maximum number of items in the input sequence?

Comment: Are you sure about the question? It is surprising to have the first element of the array be both the number of items to reverse and be part of the slice so reversed.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *reverse(int *arr,int n){
    int i, temp;

    for(i = 0; i < --n ; i++){
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[n];
        arr[n] = temp;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Note: the number of items to reverse is not supposed to be `n`, it is supposed to be the initial value of `arr[0]`

Comment: I do not think that's very do so. It is ridiculous.

Comment: I wouldn't either, but `"since the first number is a 2"` would seem to contradict `n` being meaningful for anything besides an upper limit. Either that or the OP outright misunderstood the very task now being asked about (a definite possibility). And no, I didn't down vote your answer. If the OP misunderstood the actual problem, your's is very likely a *correct* solution.

Comment: @WhozCraig but `"the problem is to reverse the first n integers of an array"`.

Comment: Again, I agree. Unfortunately the statements that follow contradict that very problem, as `n` is never mentioned again and the very number of values to reverse is assessed to be the first element value of the array. "{2,4,1,3} would be reversed to {4,2,1,3} since the first number is a 2". It is a dreadfully written question, as it is impossible to fix something if you don't know how it is supposed to work.

Comment: The title *Reversing an array of the first n numbers in C programming* disagrees with the OP's explanation. As with comments and code, they are probably both wrong.  The question deserves a down vote until clarified.

Comment: I think the interpretation of the OP is incorrect.  I want discussions to end with this.

Comment: A good illustration of the famous *upto* operator: `i <-- n` (just joking)

Comment: It isn't  to be moved  If the beginning of the elements has a special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You try and reverse the subarray twice, but fail to swap elements and go one step too far.  You should stop at the middle of the array:

```
int *reverse(int *arr, int n) {
    int w, q = arr[0];
    if (q > n) {
        /* handle this error! */
        return NULL;
    }
    for (w = 0; w < --q; w++) {
        int e = arr[w];
        arr[w] = arr[q];
        arr[q] = e;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the code to reverse the first n numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int arr [10] = {5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int i,n=arr[0];
for (i=0; i<n--; ++i){
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i]=arr[n];
    arr[n] = temp;

       }
           for (i=0; i<10; ++i){
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);

       }}
```

Comment: Did you even try this code?  It prints `6 2 3 4 5 5 7 8 9 10`.  Not what the OP expects

Comment: thank you, I didn't run it, I was confident it was correct, thank you for pointing that out!